# Get the url of cron job

Tags: cron

I have to find the url from where the cron job calls an API.
I tried `<?=$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];?>` in the cron file but it returned empty and also `<? phpinfo() ?>` did not help. 
Cron command: `* * * * * php -q /home/karenib/public_html/scr/cron.php`

Comment: is the shorthand php tag enabled in php.ini? try `<?php print_r($_SERVER); ?>`

Comment: yes it is enabled!

Comment: show the cron tab command please

Comment: *  *  *  *  *  php -q /home/karenib/public_html/scr/cron.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<?=$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];?>` will will not be populated when running it from a cronjob like `php -q /home/karenib/public_html/scr/cron.php`, since the file is not accessed via HTTP.

You can pass the host through params like

```
php -q /home/karenib/public_html/scr/cron.php -h=http://example.com
```

And access it like

```
$host = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] : getopt('h:');
```

However, if you still need the `HTTP_HOST` populated, you can use curl like

```
curl http://example.com/path/to/cron.php &> /dev/null
```